# Unable to install Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider into my vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, azure, redis

Could not install package 'Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider 4.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: It looks like that package may require .NET 4.6.2 or higher. Version 3.0.2 definitely supports .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: @jmcilhinney version 3.0.2 of  'Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider' ??

Comment: What else would I possibly be talking about?

Comment: Thanks man ! I could fix that .